# Use a 2.8" TFT with my Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo, tft

for 2.8" diagonal color touchscreen TFT:

Readme states:
"Works with any classic Arduino '328. Solder closed three jumpers to use the ICSP header for use with Leonardo or Mega"

What should I solder? See image.[image]

Comment: The things you should solder are on the TFT - we need a picture of that to point you to the right bit.

Comment: Thanks. How would I have guessed? Here's the underside of the TFT.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that display doesn't have a touch screen, only a tft and sd card. The modifications you would need to make pertain only to the SD card and the nonexistent touch screen interface. The tft portion should work with any arduino since it is a bit banged 8 bit parallel interface.